# Cropping regions in an image

Tags: python, opencv

How to get the region between the  2 digits in the below image. I am using `opencv` and `python`

## Input Image

[image]

## Output Images/Regions

[image]

### Region 1

[image: Region 1]

### Region 2

[image: Region 2]

### Region 3

[image: Region 3]

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the exact size of the crop boxes then its easy

```
box_count = 3
box_w = 50
box_h = 50
regions = []

for r in range(1,box_count+1):
    regions.append(img[(r-1)*box_h:r*box_h, 0:box_w]) #img is the image

for region in regions:
    cv2.imshow("r", region)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

Comment: The box height may vary.